# SQL query xml data from varchar(max) column

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

I have a table called `Content` which has a `varchar(max)` column called `data`.

The data in this column is in XML format, and I want to query an attribute in the XML.

Below is the top couple of lines of the XML, it is the `p3:manifestId` I want to query so my output would basically be Some_Data (I've obviously desensitized this).

Is this possible?

```
<manifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:p3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      p3:manifestDateTime="2016-02-17T17:34:29.5925096Z" 
      p3:manifestVersion="1.1" p3:manifestId="Some_Data">
  <p3:productList>
    <p3:product p3:releaseDateTime="2016-02-17T17:34:29.5925096Z"         p3:installSeqId="2" p3:uninstallSeqId="2" p3:releaseNum="1" p3:productType="doc" p3:productId="WEDREZ020RRRP0GGG001" p3:mfgCode="GIRE">
```

Comment: Please tag your dbms.

Comment: If it stores XML - why isn't the datatype `XML` (instead of `VARCHAR(MAX)`) ? That would be much more efficient, and the querying would be just so much easier.... you should always use the **most appropriate** data type.!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried, and what error messages or problems you're having? I'll mention right now that the key is properly including the name-space definitions and references in your query.

Comment: Is this question solved? Wasn't there a comment below my answer, that this works for you? As you are new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions.  Happy Coding!

Comment: Hi, sorry yeah this is solved, so thank you very much for that, great answer. I do have another question though. I now want to query another value, I've updated the xml in the question to show what I want. It's the p3:productId I want to query, I'm struggling to drill down through the xml to get this value, can you help?

Comment: Hi Andy, please avoid chameleon questions... StackOverflow is not only a site to get help, but also a huge archive of answered questions. Therefore the principle: One issue - one question. The initial question was about **How do I read the `p3:manifestId`**, which is solved. Please start a new question for the new problem and place a link here.

Comment: ok, sorry for my rubbishness :o(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing which might be complicated here, are the namespaces. How is this XML generated? It is quite unusual to see the same namespace (`http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`) as default and with two different aliases...

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXML VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
('<manifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:p3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          p3:manifestDateTime="2016-02-17T17:34:29.5925096Z" 
          p3:manifestVersion="1.1" p3:manifestId="Some_Data">
   <!--Some more stuff-->
   </manifest>');
```

--This approach does not look at namespaces at all. I use the wildcard `*:`

```
SELECT CAST(YourXML AS XML).value(N'(/*:manifest/@*:manifestId)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @mockup;
```

--This approach declares all needed namespaces in advance (best approach in most cases):

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
                          ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS p3)
SELECT CAST(YourXML AS XML).value(N'(/manifest/@p3:manifestId)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @mockup;
```

--This approach is usefull, if you really do not need more than one value. I use one alias `ns1` for all different occurances of this namespace:

```
SELECT CAST(YourXML AS XML).value(N'declare namespace ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
                                    (/ns1:manifest/@ns1:manifestId)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @mockup;
```